# How to automatically assign each valuein a db query to a variable array?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there some kind of short cut to apply all values from all selected rows of a query to their own arrays?

i.e. if i have rows: Colour, Size, and Shape, isn't there some short cut where i can put all retrieved values from colours into array $x[], all values from size in array $y[], etc, just by using a keyword, naming the arrays, and listing them in order of the rows i want them associated with?

Or is this the easiest way to do it?:

```
$i = 0;
while ($row =...)
{
    $colour[$i] = $row[0];
    $Size[$i] = $row[1];
    $Shape[$i] = $row[2];
    $i++;
}
```

I guess it's not that much code, but if your database has 20 rows i would imagine it could save some time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the easiest way to do it, you can compact it more by skipping `$i` and assigning by `list`:

```
list($colour[],$Size[],$Shape[]) = $row;
```

If `$row` can be changed from numerical indexed array to associative array, you can use [variables variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) syntax to assign values:

```
foreach($row as $arrayName => $value){
    array_push($$arrayName, $value);
}
```